# Sql select url regex

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, url, select

So I have to find the urls which contains the word 'foo' for example . I want to do this with a regex like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE url = regex`. The url is `https//...` OR `http://....` and I need to find the word `foo` for example in the url. What I actually want is a regex which will check if `foo` is in the hostname or in the path. Thanks for help!

**EDIT :**

I want to find a faster alternative with regex because `LIKE '%foo%'` is very slow on my table.

Comment: Add the table structure to the question.

Comment: `id` `url` `other unimportant information` `img`

Comment: Those are the columns, not the structure. Add the column types and indexes. Also define `very slow`, seconds, minutes, etc.

Comment: I have a index for id and a fulltext for url and sometimes it's approximately fast sometimes it stucks and doesn't output nothing, it's strange and that's why I would like a regex and also I use `MATCH AGAINST` for the fulltext search.

Comment: `fast` is not an approximate measurement. What are we talking about here? When does it get stuck? How long is it stuck for? Is the sticking consistent; e.g. always on `foo`? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: `LIKE` is faster than `REGEXP`; live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIKE` with the `%` wildcard operator.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE url LIKE '%foo%'`

Comment: I already did and for the dimension of my table it takes 2-3 min to execute the query...

Comment: Well that would be an incredibly useful piece of information to have included in your original post. You're not looking for a way to get URLs with "foo" in it as your question states, you're looking for a faster alternative to `LIKE`. The bottom line is that there is no incredibly efficient way to wildcard match on string data in SQL. Make sure that your table has a `FULLTEXT INDEX`. Generally speaking, full-table scans are frowned upon in MySQL.